# Do variables defined in subroutine carry over into an entry (within the subroutine)?

Tags: fortran

In my subroutine I define an array and then fill it with numbers before the entry is created.  In my program I also call the subroutine before the entry.  In my entry I use this array - but, it seems to go back to zero in the entry, whereas it was not zero in the subroutine.

Without copying out all of my code, this is the section of the subroutine that is relevant:

```
      SRL(1)=SRW+4
      DO 10 I=2,NLAY
10    SRL(I)=SRL(I-1)+MLAY(I-1)+1
      LAST=SRL(NLAY)+MLAY(NLAY)
      SRW=LAST
      RETURN

      ENTRY STLOAD(NUMG,M,L,S,T,SS,TS,W,TAU)
      N=SRL(L)+M-1
      READ(10,REC=N) W1,TAU1,S1,T1,SS1,TS1
```

This is where I'm having trouble, because it says my record number is not positive, and when I write out what `SRL(1)` (in this case `L` is `1`) is, it says it is zero, but in the code block above the entry when I write out what `SRL(1)` is it is `5`.

The variable `SRL(L)` is declared at the start of the subroutine.

Comment: Do you use a debugger?

Comment: I am the debugger. @Peter

Comment: I know I'm going to regret this, but: do you have the `save` attribute set on `SRL`? (Hint: Don't use `entry`, don't use `save`).

Comment: No, I don't @AlexanderVogt, and I am simply trying to compile the code I didn't write it so I'm unsure how to rewrite it.  Should I try to rewrite entry as a function? Is there any way I can save the array SRL and pass it to this function?

Comment: Better rewrite the subroutine, so that it additionally has `SRL` as an output. Then you can transform your entry into another subroutine with `SRL` as (additional) input.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, the `SRL` array is probably missing a `save` attribute. However, considering the age of that code, it might be that the compiler they used saved the variables by default or specific compile options were used.

It's probably too much to hope that this was in some way documented, but you can force the behaviour with e.g. `-fno-automatic` for `gfortran` or `-save` for `ifort`. I'm guessing any other compiler will also allow such options to be set.

Comment: best to actually specify `save` in the code.  (of course then you do need to study the code to see if anything else needs to be `save`d.)